# Maven release:perform on azure pipeline fails as it can't read password for the repo

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, maven-release-plugin

I have a parent pom where I have used maven-release-plugin, with the artifact that needs to be pushed to Azure artifacts. I was able to make it work on my local, and now am trying to automate it using azure pipeline, but I get the below error for the `mvn release:perform`.

Error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:3.0.0-M1:perform (default-cli) on project my-parent-repo: Unable to checkout from SCM
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The git-clone command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] Cloning into 'checkout'...
[ERROR] fatal: could not read Password for 'https:********@dev.azure.com': terminal prompts disabled
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

My pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<scm>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:https://$(PAT)@dev.azure.com/my-org/my-prjt/_git/my-parent-repo/</developerConnection>
  <tag>HEAD</tag>
</scm>
<groupId>dispute</groupId>
<artifactId>my-parent</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>Microservice DI parent</name>
<description>DI microservice parent </description>
<distributionManagement>  
  <!-- Publish the versioned releases here -->  
  <repository>  
    <id>repo</id>  
    <name>Artifact repo</name>  
    <url>https://xxx.pkgs.visualstudio.com/2abc/_packaging/my-maven-artifacts/maven/v1</url>  
  </repository>  
</distributionManagement>  

<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>my-maven-artifacts</id>
        <url>
            https://xxx.pkgs.visualstudio.com/2abc/_packaging/my-maven-artifacts/maven/v1
        </url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>Pod4-artifacts</id>
        <url>
            https://xxx.pkgs.visualstudio.com/2abc/_packaging/my-maven-artifacts/maven/v1
        </url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<properties>
    <!-- Build properties -->
    <maven.version>3.3.9</maven.version>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>
</project>
```

Fixes tried:
I have enabled `Allow scripts to access the OAuth token` on the Agent job. I have also provided the permissions for the Project Collection Service Accounts and Project Collection Build Service to create tag, branch, contribute under Repositories.
Also, have a ci-settings.xml with the username and password for the repo id, which am providing as arguments in the Maven task in the Azure pipeline.
`-e -B -s $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/ci-settings.xml`

If there is anything am missing, please let me know. Please note, it worked perfectly in my local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using PAT token instead of OAuth token, we do not need enable the option `Allow scripts to access the OAuth token`. If you want to use this, you could use this URL

```
https://$env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN@dev.azure.com/my-org/my-prjt/_git/my-parent-repo
```

We should provide the permission for the account `Project Collection Build Service(Org name)` to create tag, branch, contribute under the select repo permission instead of configure the permission under the `All Repositories` permission page.

We could also try to set the `PAT token` in the pom file instead of variable.